# Photoshop: "Convert to smart object" abandons layer blending mode

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Cutting a PSD comp for a website I'm building, and some of the layers have a particular blending mode set. Now, normally when I'm cutting PNG, I convert all layers into a single smart object, then copy the object to a new doc and export for web.

However, when I convert a layer that has Multiply set for the blending mode, it loses whatever effects the blending mode gave it. Sometimes a background spontaneously appears, sometimes a feathered edge becomes a solid box.

Is there a way to flatten and export these layers at "face value", eg cut the graphics without compromising the way they look, regardless of blending mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often Flatten the document before I set up the guides and slices.  IIRC, "Flatten" is an option under the Layers menu.  Or I can dig up the key command if you tell me what PS version and OS you're using.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! What would I do in the case of transparent pngs? Often I need to cut out a logo without taking the background from the layer behind with it.

Comment: Delete whatever layers behind it are causing the background to be non-transparent, then flatten it.  Transparent areas should stay transparent even after flattenting.